# How to run an embedded elastic search instance for testing

Tags: elasticsearch, specs2

I'm working in a setup that has an embedded [elastic search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) instance for unit testing purposes, but when I run the tests continuously with sbt (`~test-only <my-test>`) the system becomes increasingly unstable until it freezes and has to be killed with fire.

Things I'm having a hard time getting to work properly are:

- isolation
- cleanup
- shutdown

What is the proper way to set this up, (solutions preferably using specs2, but Java based is also welcome)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest you to have a look at the [elasticsearch-test](https://github.com/tlrx/elasticsearch-test) project on github. You can easily add it as a dependency to your project and use its handy annotations to start test nodes, create indices and so on.

Comment: thanks for the tip, it looks like this is going to solve a lot of my problems.

Comment: what about if you are using python?

Comment: are there examples/snippetes of how to use it?

Comment: @javanna Is this still a best approach. As I am using elasticsearch v5.1.1 and there is no support as such in the library.